# Absolute Positioning + Negative Margins distorted with window resize

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper `div` that I wanted centered in the window. I used the following CSS to accomplish this:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: -480px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

The only problem is, when I alter the size of the browsing window, I cannot see anything left of the halfway point of the window. I know this is because of the negative margin, but is there any way to correct this?

I am trying to float it over some other `div`s therefore that auto margin trick will not work.

Here is the link for what I have: [dev.connectionsquad.com](http://dev.connectionsquad.com).

Comment: I am aware that, that centers a div in a window, but I need the wrapper to "float" over some other divs and stay centered. The link for what I am trying is dev.connectionsquad.com

Comment: so how about 2 divs one in another - first for 100% width of the window and your div inside that gets auto margin and places centered?

Comment: Again that does not allow the div to be above another div. It only centers it within it's parent element. The wrapper itself is the parent element, but I want it above several other divs.

Comment: i mean first div positioned absolute and another without absolute

Comment: i found also that this line: `<img src="Resources/TextLogo.png">` makes my browser put a horizontal scroll bar - try to make it a background in a div style, not an image itself

Comment: I didn't try your second idea, but your other post gave me an idea. I figured out a solution. Thanks for your help! Basically what I did was take the divs I wanted in the background and gave them absolute positioning like you said, then I gave the wrapper a higher z-index with a relative position and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following for any div that centers in the page.
    `body {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #wrapper {
      width: 1080px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      text-align: left;
    }`

With some browsers you must use text-align: center on the body tag to make the div center in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rewriting your code and making it standards-compliant, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
}
body {
    background: #222;
    text-align: center
}
#content {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 50%;
    min-height: 400px;
    top: 10%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    background-image: url('/img/noise.png');
    border: 5px solid #000
}
#background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -125px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #666;
    background-image: url('/img/placeholder.png');
    border-top: 5px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #eee;
}
a:active, a:visited {
    color: #075f76
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

See [HTML5 - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5).